# Strict Type Checking in Objective-C via Macros

Tags: objective-c, macros

Occasionally, during development/debugging, I want to ensure that an object is of a certain type:

```
PageTopBottom *newPage = [notification object];
assert([newPage isKindOfClass:[PageTopBottom class]]);
```

which I've worked into this

```
#define assertType(_var_, _class_) assert([_var_ isKindOfClass:[_class_ class]])
```

and

```
PageTopBottom *newPage = (id)[notification object];
assertType(newPage, PageTopBottom);
```

but now I'd like to, if possible, just use

```
assertType(newPage)
```

**Is it possible to get information about a variable's declared type from the variable?**

I'm not positive that I'm framing the question correctly, but any answer that gets me to be able to assertType with one parameter would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to get information about a variable's declared type from the variable?

No.  By the time the program is running, that information is lost.  In your case, newPage is just a 32 or 64 bit number that points to a bit of memory that holds an Objective-C object.

I think your original unmacro'd version is the right thing to do here:

```
assert([newPage isKindOfClass:[PageTopBottom class]]);
```

That perfectly documents the assumption you are making i.e. that you assume newPage is an instance of PageTopBottom or one of its subclasses and it's completely clear to anybody who understands Objective-C.  Your macro version slightly obfuscates that, in that somebody coming across it in the code might beleive it is asserting that newPage is a PageTopBottom and not one of its subclasses (you could change the name of the macro to prevent that, I suppose, but I just wouldn't bother).

**Edit**

What you could do is combine the declaration and assertion in one:

```
#define DECLARE_AND_ASSERT_IS_KIND_OF_CLASS(T, V, I)    T* V = (T*)(I); assert([(V) isKindOfClass: [(T) class])
```

which would work like this:

```
DECLARE_AND_ASSERT_IS_KIND_OF_CLASS(PageTopBottom, newPage, [notification object]);
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks. I will at least change my macro to be called `ASSERT_IS_KIND_OF_CLASS` for now. I kind of don't want to mess with the declaration if possible, since I will remove the asserts once they're no longer needed.

Comment: Hi, let me know if you think I should open a separate question: what if the problem were to compare parameters to the signature of a method? In other words, do a strict typing parameter check...

Comment: @Yar:  yes, separate question I think.

Comment: Thx! Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890695/strict-type-checking-in-objective-c-part-2

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, with Objective-C++ there are two options:

1. Write a template function

   template void assertType(T* obj) { ... }
2. For a pointer `X* x`, use `NSClassFromString([NSString stringWithUTF8String:typeid(*x).name()])`.

Without using C++, you might be able to use GCC extension `typeof`, but I'm not sure if `[typeof(*x) class]` is a legit operation...

Comment: Thanks @Yuji. I'm not sure this is correct or not, but the question was about objective-c. Can I mix?

Comment: Yes, just change the file extension to `.mm` instead of `.m`. Then you can mix Objective-C and C++. It's not that two class systems are unified... it's just that you can use both.

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor only processes text; it has no knowledge of type, which is why it's sometimes considered 'dangerous'.  The only way I could see doing it is wrapping the variable declarations in a macro, which I would strongly advise against, and probably wouldn't actually cut down on the code or complexity.

Also, shouldn't you check the type *before* casting?

Comment: I'm not sure it matters whether you assert before or after casting, since you're going to blow up regardless :) Thanks +1