# Strict Type Checking in Objective-C Part 2

Tags: objective-c, ios

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838259) I was looking for a way to ensure that a variable is of a certain type using a define. But sometimes I have this situation:

```
- (void) theSituation:(Thinger*)thinger {
    ASSERT_IS_KIND_OF(thinger, Thinger);
    // etc. etc.
```

Then I started thinking that, **for debugging purposes ONLY**, it might be nice to be able to call something like:

```
- (void) theSituation:(Thinger*)thinger {
    ASSERT_INPUT_PARAMS_ARE_OF_CORRECT_TYPES();
    // etc. etc.
```

The question is: could you check that parameters of a method are of the right type (using `isKindOf`) via `#define`, and how would you do this (in general terms)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the arguments of a method (using `method_copyArgumentType` as mentioned in the other answer), the "type" it returns is either a C type (like int, float, etc) or just Object (returned as a "@"). Sadly it's not possible to get the objective-C type that a method is expecting — that information is lost when you compile.

Answer to a similar problem found [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg25155.html).

Comment: Fascinating. I'm beginning to understand that the "type" of a variable simply doesn't exist as a runtime concept whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... Interesting question. I have a few things that should work (theoratically).

You can get the function name that is being executed using `__func__`. (See [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html)).

You can get the Selector from a string:

```
SEL selector = selectorFromString(@"doWork");
```

You can get Method object of an instance of a class using [objective C runtime](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418).

```
Method *m = class_getInstanceMethod(self, selector);
```

You can get number of arguments of a method from:

```
method_getNumberOfArguments
```

you can get argument type using

```
method_copyArgumentType
```

And from here you should be able to assert.

I know, long shot - I have not tried to run the code. I'll update the answer if I get on a Mac soon.

Comment: Thanks, I've now come to understand that it's impossible because THE TYPE INFORMATION SIMPLY ISN'T THERE.